# Script to delete docker images older than X days on Private Docker Registry

Tags: shell, docker-registry

I have a private Docker registry, and I'm looking for a script (either shell or python) to delete images older than X Days. I found some examples but there are deleting all images except the latest tag which is not what I'm expecting.

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: if images are files, than file selection based on modification date can be done with 'find' or with some shell patterns

Comment: How are you defining "older than X days"? Are you looking at the created time in the image config? Do you have multi-platform images? Do you care about when the image was pushed or last used? Do you need to preserve some number of images?

Comment: My Docker Registry is installed on a Linux server, and each Images are generated automatically  by our CI/CD which is using a tag naming different from "latest". As we are launching pipelines quite often, we would need to delete images older than 100 days as for sure there are not used anymore and it will help us to save memory !

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70464116/596285

Comment: A note of caution, if your private registry is `registry:2`, aka github.com/distribution/distribution, the included GC will delete too much if you have multi-platform images. For more details, see https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/3178